# mingw make gives error code -107374181 when running executable

Tags: c, windows, continuous-integration, github-actions, linkage

I have been having some issues with my CI under Windows (none of the issue occur under my own Windows installation). I am using GitHub Actions as a CI provider.

When make tries to run an executable linked against a certain DLL (which seemingly works fine in earlier invocations linked against the same DLL) with cmd.exe as the shell, it causes the following output (according to `mingw32-make -d`):

```
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\make3992-9.bat
Batch file contents:
    @echo off
    cd lib && ..\\test\\unit\\gencore_test.exe
cd lib && ..\\test\\unit\\gencore_test.exe
CreateProcess(C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\make3992-9.bat,C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\make3992-9.bat,...)
Putting child 000000000245A570 (gencore_test) PID 38130688 on the chain.
Live child 000000000245A570 (gencore_test) PID 38130688 
Reaping losing child 000000000245A570 PID 38130688 
mingw32-make: *** [test/unit/gencore_test.mk:8: gencore_test] Error -1073741819
Cleaning up temp batch file C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\make3992-9.bat
Removing child 000000000245A570 PID 38130688 from chain.
```

(The DLL is contained in the `lib` folder which is why I `cd`into it before invoking the exe.)

This error occurs before `main` gets called (as I have a call to `puts` as the first statement), which makes me think that this is an issue with the lib loader.

I can only presume this is a bogus error code, obviously searching for it online yielded no results though I haven't searched the make or mingw source code to see if its ever mentioned.

If I replace the `SHELL` with `sh.exe` it instead gives the error 2816, which also doesn't occur on my personal Windows installation, and isn't documented on MSDN as a known error (the docs skip from 2404 to 3000).

I think this is to do with the DLL since it occurs before program runtime, but the fact that other executables linked against the same library work fine makes me think that it could be an issue in the build process - so here is the compilation and linkage of the executable:

```
clang -c -std=c17 -DWIN=1 -DDWN=2 -DLNX=3 -DBSD=4 -DPLATFORM=WIN -g -O0 -DMODE=DEBUG -D_MT -D_DEBUG -Igenesis/gencore/include  -Igenesis/vendor/c11compat/mesa/include -Igenesis/vendor/dirent/include -o test/unit/gencore/main.o test/unit/gencore/main.c
clang -o test/unit/gencore_test.exe test/unit/gencore/main.o  -lshlwapi.lib -Wl,-nodefaultlib:libcmt.lib -llibcmtd.lib -fPIE -Llib -lgencore
```

(IK some of that is probably irrelevant but it could be causing an esoteric conflict that I'm not aware of so I left it in)

The fact that it works fine on my own install with the same invocation, and given that I installed Windows specifically to resolve this problem and as such am as close to a vanilla installation as can be (using the same llvm release as the CI etc.) makes me think that its a configuration thing on the side of GitHub actions? But then again some executables work and some don't so its really up in the air.

Thank you very much if you know whats going on here and are able to help

The repository is here: https://github.com/Th3T3chn0G1t/GenesisEngine, though the build system is rather convoluted so if I missed a detail or something needs clarification I can distill it here.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer - it turns out that Github CI can undergo some filesystem corruption and that it is a known issue, similar issues began cropping up in my Linux CI after this.

The solution I had was just to disable CI and re-enable it later on in order to possibly get a different host.